# How to attach debugger to script

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

In my .NET application there is a window you can type code into (scripts, language is C#. They are run through reflection)

I need a possibility of debugging scripts in compiled application just like in Visual Studio. Is it possible to use MS Debugger or any other for that? And how if yes?

Edit: Is it possible to do  without Visual Studio?

Well, broadly speaking, it's like that:
User enters code, presses "Run". Sсript is being built in a .dll. And then it's being run through reflection ( rather through methodInfo.Invoke() ).

Comment: Note that there is a bug in .NET 4 (fixed in .NET 4.5) that prevents breakpoints from being re-evaluated when 're-running' the same code (but in a new in-memory assembly of course). https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/684089/debugger-fails-to-re-evaluate-breakpoints-when-new-code-is-executed-in-a-transient-assembly

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() to stop running and open debugger.
Or System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() to launches and attaches a debugger to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Start your app, then in Visual Studio, choose Debug > Attach to Process, and select your process.  This will certainly let you debug the precompiled parts of your app.  As for debugging the user-entered scripts...I suppose that depends on how you're running them.

Edit: on rereading your question, I think you're asking if it's possible to debug the user code *using your app*, not using Visual Studio.  If that's it, I'm not sure if that's possible.  It strikes me as potentially being very difficult, but it depends on how you're exactly you're running the user's code.  More details would help.